# How to tell Windows 7 NOT to search for LAN printers on start-up?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I take my notebook to work and I have configured the printers there. I obviously don't have that printer at home so I want Windows not search for that prineter every time on start-up.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I found some information that looked similar to this at http://answers.recipester.org/question/23067/how-do-you-disable-Automatically-search-for-Network-folders-and-Printers-in-Windows-7%3F.

> Open Windows Explorer, press  +
>   , then choose "Folder Options", you
>   will find the settings located in
>   "View" tab.

I tried looking at this myself but didn't see a printer setting. Maybe you will. I will let you know if I discover anything else.

-Good Luck

Comment: nop, I don't see it either :(